# Make dc.js charts without the actual records sent to browser

Tags: d3.js, charts, dc.js

I have a fully working page with multiple charts with the crossfilter functionality.

> Is it possible to create charts without sending all the data(>million
>   records) to the client browser?

Right now, I use all the data jsons to crossfilter object and subsequently create charts out of it.

I am thinking of creating groupby queries at the backend and directly using the count of results to somehow generate charts.
Is it possible? If not, how should I go about doing this>

Comment: If you can partially aggregate the data on the backend before sending it to crossfilter, that's probably the easiest solution. Often not all the dimensions would be interesting for the user to filter. For example, maybe you are using reduceCount (the default group aggregation) but you could have a count field instead, and a row for every possible combination of the dimensions. I've not seen any robust server side replacement for crossfilter yet.

Comment: So, right now I'm working on financial data and have a page similar to [dc.js demo page](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/). How will partial aggregation work in that scenario? Even if I get the aggregated data(e.g. group-count for each quarter) from backend how would I create charts using this data, since they required crossfilter object and that requires actual data in json, csv, etc.

Comment: Also, I could not find any current projects working on this solution. I would love to contribute in that area. Similar feature is available in datatables. There they send out ajax request for every command(searching, filtering, sorting, etc with pagination)

Comment: You would still use crossfilter on the front end but you would use reduceSum on the count column instead of reduceCount. It doesn't work in every scenario, but it's common that what you want to display to the user is more granular than the source data. As I said, I don't know of a good server-side replacement, only hacks. You could maybe look at MapD but I think that's more about throwing GPUs at the problem.